# Not fetching latest record after Thread.sleep() in while loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code

```
//This will load storeHeartbeat record from db
StoreHeartbeat storeHeartbeat = storeHeartbeatService.findByStoreId(context, locationId);
while (true)
  {
    if (storeHeartbeat.getCurrentHeatbeatDatetime().isAfter(jobTriggeredTime))
       break;
    else
       TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(300000);
    //Again loading storeHeartbeat to get updated value.
    storeHeartbeat = storeHeartbeatService.findByStoreId(context, locationId);    
  }
```

Here I have a infinite loop, I am checking for a condition if the condition matches I want to come out of the loop, otherwise I want to sleep for 5 min and re-try again by loading the latest heartbeat record from db.

Issue : I am not getting updated heartbeat record, always getting old record which was loaded initially, even though I am updating record(while thread is sleeping).

Any suggestions what am I missing here? 
Is there any thread cache holding old value? If so how can I achieve this?

Note : Condition works fine no issue with it

Edit : Here is my findByStoreId method

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public StoreHeartbeat findByStoreId(Context context, String storeId)
{
    QStoreHeartbeatEntity qStoreHeartbeat = QStoreHeartbeatEntity.storeHeartbeatEntity;
    JPQLQuery query = createQueryObject(context);
    StoreHeartbeat result = (StoreHeartbeat) query.from(qStoreHeartbeat).where(
            qStoreHeartbeat.storeId.eq(storeId == null ? "XXXXXXXXXXXX" : storeId)).uniqueResult(qStoreHeartbeat);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the code seems  to be fine. Have you checked after debugging, what is returned by findByStoreId after every 5 min. Also, can you share the piece of code for that function as well.

Comment: It looks like your function findByStoreId() is not giving you latest value for  given context, locationId. Need more info to answer this

Comment: `Note : Condition works fine no issue with it` are you sure ?  which persistence are you using ? you may have a caching problem but in the persistence layer

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Which includes the relevant code from storeHeartbeatService.

Comment: @AmanChhabra - Yes I debugged, it is returning old record.

Comment: @All - Provided findByStoreId method where I have code to fetch storeHeartbeat record from db.

Comment: Check what is the value is returned by StoreHeartbeat result = (StoreHeartbeat) query.from(qStoreHeartbeat). If it is again the old value, then I can think of two issues, 1) The value in DB is not being properly commit by the application that is updating it. 2) The cache is not properly configured at persistence layer.

Comment: @AmanChhabra yes it is the old value. 1) I tried updating record directly on DB as well, still no use. 2) Not configured any cache on this entity

Answer (score 0):

storeHeartbeat is local variable? If yes, then thread not cache that variable otherwise add `volatile` to your class field or use `ThreadLocal` class. If you use hibernate, it may be problems with hibernate cache. To say more precisely I should see more your code